# Convert legacy sql to standard sql - Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I got the following error in big query when running the following code in standard SQL:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP("2017-10-01"), pos - 1, "DAY")) AS selected_date
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, *
     FROM 
         (FLATTEN((SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()), TIMESTAMP("2017-10-01")), '.'),'') AS h
     FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
     )))
```

Error:

> Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got ")" at [7:7]

Can anyone convert this to standard SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT d AS selected_date
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY("2017-10-01", CURRENT_DATE())) d
```

Comment: great. if not yet  - consider voting up :o)